# Change column values of CSV file based of value of another column (using awk, vim, or similar terminal command)

Tags: regex, csv, awk, terminal

I have an csv file representing bank transactions that looks like this:

```
"Date","Description","Original Description","Amount","Transaction Type","Category","Account Name","Labels","Notes"

"10/18/2012","Amazon","AMAZON.COM","27.60","debit","Shopping","CHASE COLLEGE","",""

"10/19/2012","Virgin America","VIRGIN AMER","155.90","debit","Air Travel","CREDIT CARD","",""

"10/20/2012","Airport Express","AIR EXP","16.00","credit","Credit Card Payment","CREDIT CARD","",""
```

I am trying to convert it so that the value in column 4 is +/- depending on the value of column 5. If 5 says "debit" the value of col 4 should be "-", if it says "credit", the value of col 4 should be "+"

So the output would be something like this:

```
"Date","Description","Original Description","Amount","Transaction Type","Category","Account Name","Labels","Notes"

"10/18/2012","Amazon","AMAZON.COM","-27.60","debit","Shopping","CHASE COLLEGE","",""

"10/19/2012","Virgin America","VIRGIN AMER","-155.90","debit","Air Travel","CREDIT CARD","",""

"10/20/2012","Airport Express","AIR EXP","16.00","credit","Credit Card Payment","CREDIT CARD","",""
```

What would be the best way to do this?
I had considered writing a MATLAB program with If statements to read in the file, but I would like to know if there is a simple way to do it from terminal, such as using AWK or RegEx in Vim!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you could do it with a regex (or at least a pair of them), but `awk` is much better suited. In general, awk isn't great with quoted fields, but since *every* field is quoted and we don't need to work with the first field, we can work around that.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""}$5=="credit"{$4="+"$4}$5=="debit"{$4="-"$4}1' file.csv
```

Explanation

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    # Set the input and output field separators to ",", *with* the quotes.
    FS=OFS="\",\"" 
}

# On every line where field 5 is "credit" ...
$5 == "credit" { 
    # ... Prepend "+" to the fourth field.
    $4="+"$4 
}

# On every line where the fifth field is "debit" ...
$5 == "debit" { 
    # ... Prepend "-" to the fourth field.
    $4="-"$4
}

# Print the line
1
' test.in
```

Comment: Hey! That worked, but after toying with it a little I think it would suite my needs better If instead of changing the value, I just put credit and debits in a separate column, so the "amount" column becomes "credit", the "transaction type" becomes "debit". Basically put income and expenses on two columns, 3 and 4, with the expenses column overwriting "credit or debit" on column 5.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can actually be done using VIM regex, but little complicated.

First, we identify the rows containing de word "debit", with a character like `k` for example:

`%s/\(^.*debit.*$\)/k\1`

Second, apply minus sign to the 4th column

`%s/^k\(.\{-},.\)\{3}\zs\(.\{-},\)/-\2`

Finally, reverse changes to identified rows

`%s/^k//`